# Given a population of values which each have unique uncertainties, how do I determine the mean and standard deviation of the population?

Tags: population, uncertainty

I'm trying to determine if a material has a different spectroscopic response under different conditions. In short, I measure 100 points on the sample, and the data output at each point is a data series that fits to a Voigt lineshape. However, of course, there is some noise in the data, and the fitting algorithm gives a standard error for the peak parameters (such as peak position). So for each material condition I have 100 estimated values for peak position and a unique standard error associated with each value.

An example of a histogram of my data (just the estimated values, not including standard error) for four different conditions is given below. I want to determine the sample means and standard deviations and, for example, whether the second and fourth conditions are different to some confidence interval. Can anyone suggest how to treat this? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the error in each value have expectation $0$?  Is each error independent of the other errors?  If so,  and if a set of $n$ observations have values $x_i$ and standard errors $s_i$, I would have thought you could say something like:

- The sum of the values is $\sum x_i$ with variance $\sum s_i^2$ and standard error $\sqrt{\sum s_i^2}$
- The mean of the values is $\frac1n\sum x_i$ with variance $\frac1{n^2}\sum s_i^2$ and standard error $\frac1n\sqrt{\sum s_i^2}$

Comment: The standard error according to (1/n)*sqrt(sum(s_i)^2) is ~0.02, but I don't think this can be the final answer. Inspection of the histogram shows this is standard error is too small. Taking the standard deviation of the values themselves gives ~0.3.

I guess the problem is that there are uncertainty components of the fitting (due to noise), the measurement apparatus, and the sample itself (due to inhomogeneities in the sample because I'm measuring 100 different points). I feel like there needs to be a convolution of these uncertainties, but I don't know how to compute that.

Comment: @JacobBagley Your question says each value has a standard error and there are $100$ values for each of the four conditions.  Your comment suggests something different, that there are really four values each with a standard error of its mean.  This makes a substantial difference to which mean you are using.  Incidentally if all the standard deviations are equal, say $s$, then $\frac1n\sqrt{\sum s_i^2}  = \frac1{\sqrt{n}}s$, a well-known result

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There are four sets of data, which each have 100 values, and each value has a unique uncertainty. I want to express each data set as a population (with a mean and standard deviation) and compare them to each other. I don't think it's correct to simply take the mean and standard deviation of the values because the values are not precisely known. So how does one incorporate the uncertainty of each value into the mean and standard deviation of the population?